# Updating wordpress plugins inside a docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker

Here is my scenario:

I have been developing a plugin which will be modified very often, I need to create an image using docker in which install a fresh version of wordpress and then import all the database and plugins from the development environment, ( The plug in is on github)

I managed to install wordpress on docker using https://github.com/eugeneware/docker-wordpress-nginx

Now here are my questions:

1-is there any way to modify the wordpress files and folders after it's been installed in docker(for installing plugins and using command line, not the wordpress GUI)

2-If I want to achieve what I explained above what is the best workflow?

Comment: In general you should use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/). Clone wordpress on host machine and run the image with `--volume /dir/where/wp/is/on/host:/usr/share/nginx/www`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible answers to your problem. I'm struggling with this right now as well, so YMMV.

First, if you're running the Docker container on your host, you can always pause it `docker pause`, create a new image from the running container `docker commit`, then push it to a private repository `docker push` (a live Wordpress install is probably not appropriate for the public Docker Hub). Once that's done, you can resume the container `docker unpause` and then you can go update the image on your dev system. Then come back once the upgrade is in and tested and all is good, and then `docker pull` the image and restart your service so it uses the new image.

Not a great solution, but it will work.

Based on the comment by [Tadeusz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1151982/tadeusz-%C5%81azurski), I wouldn't necessarily run your whole WP install from a data volume. They are volatile and if, for any reason, your container gets deleted and it's the only one referencing the data volume, then you lose everything (unless you keep multiple backups -- you *do* keep multiple backups, right?)

The other solution I'm considering is having plugin changes be deployed as part of the Dockerfile. A much more deliberate approach, but can be webhooked such that it automatically builds a new Docker image when you commit to your Github repo. There's discussion of doing that automatic build process [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/).
The server admin end of things on your end hosting will need to pull a the new image as I mentioned above. And done.

Of course, setting this up is left as an exercise for your dev system.

Cheers!

Comment: Any thoughts on how to manage database state in this scenario?

Comment: actually it might be more appropriate to mount the wordpress in a volume and that volume is pulled from sort of code repository and even better instead of pause the container is better to create a new one, with the udpate volume and destroy the old one.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party but I've got a decent solution to this. It isn't covered by the other answers and should also be useful to future readers.

I'm comfortably running this on an ec2 t2-micro box and so far it's worked perfectly. Wordpress, mySQL and Nginx are all installed in their own containers (via Docker compose) and Docker volumes are used to maintain both mySQL and Wordpress state. Code and additional info about the Nginx setup taken from [here](http://henrycourse.com/2018/04/18/the-start-of-summer-ft-wordpress-on-docker/).

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'

 services:
    db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: db_root_pass
        MYSQL_DATABASE: db
        MYSQL_USER: db_user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: db_pass
    nginx:
      depends_on:
        - wordpress
      image: nginx:latest
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    wordpress:
      depends_on:
        - db
      volumes:
        - wp_data:/var/www/html/wp-content
      image: wordpress:latest
      restart: always
      environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: db_user
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: db_pass
 volumes:
    db_data:
    wp_data:
```

the `db_data` volume is mapped to the mySQL data directory within the mySQL container and the `wp_data` volume is mapped to the Wordpress content directory in the Wordpress container. What you can do is configure the CLI to write to the `wp_data` directory on the host and those changes will be revealed on the Wordpress site without needing to rebuild any containers!